# How to run an aggregation update in Spring MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb

Here's my structure of the data

```js
db.record.insertMany([
    {
        _id: RECORD_ID,
        data: [
            {
                id: 'field1',
                value: 'value1'
            },
            {
                id: 'field2',
                value: 'value2'
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

And here's the query I want to run

```js
let RECORD_ID = 'record1';
let MODIFIED_FIELDS = ['field2'];
let NEW_DATA = [
    {
        id: 'field2',
        value: 'value 2 updated'
    },
    {
        id: 'field3',
        value: 'value 3'
    }
]

db.record.updateOne(
    {
        _id: RECORD_ID,
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                data: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                        {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$data",
                                as: "item",
                                cond: {
                                    $not: {
                                        $in: ["$$item.id", MODIFIED_FIELDS],
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        NEW_DATA
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

As I have the need of doing $concatArrays operation in my update, I have to use aggregation pipeline. Now my question is, is it possible to run this update in Spring MongoDB? I can see that Spring's `MongoTemplate` class provides an `updateOne` method that takes `AggregationUpdate` as a parameter, however I've been unable to come up with a good documentation and write this query. Problematic parts are the `concatArrays` with input data and the `filter`.

P.S. All the documentation I can find about `concatArrays` refers to using it with variables inside the aggregation, not with input array parameter.